# Adding a query var to taxonomy term archive - gets redirected to the other taxonomy archive page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query, terms, advanced-taxonomy-queries, template-redirect

I want to pass another query var in the URL through a form while I'm on a taxonomy archive page.

The URL would look like so

```
http://www.mydomain.com/tax_1/term_55/?&tax_1=term_1&tax_2=term2&orderby=modified
```

- `tax_1` is the other other taxonomy
- `tax_2` is the taxonomy I'm currently on - if the user passes this var eventually the taxonomy archive he's currently on should display results for another term

If I attempt to load this URL I will be always redirected to `tax_1` taxonomy archive page for the term I passed. No matter if I set or no any var for `tax_2`.

Has this something to do with template_redirect? How to adjust it?

Thanks

### UPDATE

Actually I realised this is pretty easy to do with post type archives and multiple taxonomies. I could create a form to redirect according to user selection to the post type archive with advanced taxonomy query vars (just use a different action and point to the post type archive). Still, I'd like to know if what I wanted to do in a taxonomy term archive is possible...

Comment: Is that a typo? Your query vars should start with a question mark like   `http://www.example.com/tax_1/term_55/?tax_1=term_1&tax_2=term2&orderby=modified`

Comment: yes sorry that was a typo on Stackexchange only, I will edit my question